# Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So im making an application for course information retrieval, the process basically from first, 1. stoplist/stopword 2. stemming 3. indexing 4. count term wieghting 5. counting vektor

but everytime, in the term weighting process, it always stuck with this error
and this error always appear the same data (at data number 28699)(there is about 30K+ data to count the weight)

heres the error

```
07-18 09:13:00.249 18878-19176/faiznoeris.tbitugaspraktek.temubalikinformasi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                           Process: faiznoeris.tbitugaspraktek.temubalikinformasi, PID: 18878
                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:151)
                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:123)
                                                                                               at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:236)
                                                                                               at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:268)
                                                                                               at stbi.Bobot.doInBackground(Bobot.java:113)
                                                                                               at stbi.Bobot.doInBackground(Bobot.java:23)
                                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

heres my **DBHelper.java**

```
public boolean updateTbIndex_Bobot(double bobot, int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    try {
        contentValues.put(DATA_COLUMN_BOBOT, bobot);
        db.update(DATA_INDEX_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DATA_COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /*finally {
        //db.close();
    }*/
    return false;
}

public Cursor getAllDataIndex() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        //Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_INDEX_TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + DATA_COLUMN_ID, null);

        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(QUERY_GET_ALL_DATA_INDEX, null);
        return res;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and heres my **Bobot.java**

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //db = new DBHelper(context);
    //n = db.getTotalDataIndex();

    db = new DBHelper(context);
    Cursor rs = db.getAllDataIndex();

    if (rs.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!rs.isAfterLast()) {
            //db.openDataBase();
            str_term = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATA_COLUMN_TERM));

            id = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATA_COLUMN_ID));
            index_count = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATA_COLUMN_COUNTINDEX));
            Nterm = db.getWordFreq(str_term);

            Log.d(TAG_LOG_D, "BEFORE COUNT: N: " + n + " | NTERM: " + Nterm + " | INDEX_COUNT: " + index_count + " | LOG: " + String.valueOf(Math.log10((n / Nterm))) + " FOR TERM: " + str_term);

            hasilbobot = index_count * Math.log10((n / Nterm));

            if (db.updateTbIndex_Bobot(hasilbobot, id)) {
                Log.d(TAG_LOG_D, "TERM: " + str_term + " | BOBOT: " + hasilbobot + " WORD KE: " + counterLoadingBar + " / " + loadingMax);
            }

            counterLoadingBar++;
            progressHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadingBar.setProgress(counterLoadingBar);
                    tvInfo.setText("Current Progress = Bobot | " + counterLoadingBar + " / " + loadingMax + " term");
                }
            });

            rs.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Maybe db.getWordFreq(str_term); implementation is relevant, can you add that code as well?